# illegal start of simple expression Scala

Tags: json, scala, spray

I have two version of Scala compiler 2.11.12 and 2.12.4. I have a code which overrides read and write method of a json protocol. The code is something like this.

```
implicit lazy val abcJsonProtocol: RootJsonFormat[XYZ] = new 
RootJsonFormat[XYZ] {

  override def write(obj: XYZ): JsValue = {
    val baseJson =
      JsObject(
    “abc” -> obj.efg.toJson,
    “ikj” -> obj.mno.toJson
    )

    obj
      .map(value => JsObject(baseJson.fields + (“wxy” -> 
      value.toJson)))
    .getOrElse(baseJson)
  }

  override def read(value: JsValue): XYZ = {
    val jsObject = value.asJsObject
    jsObject.getFields("abc",
      "kJ") match {
      case Seq(efg, mno) =>
        XYZ(
          efg = efg.convertTo[String],
          mno = mno.convertTo[String],

        )
    }
  }
   }
```

The error is something likes this

```
illegal start of simple expression
[error]           )
[error]           ^
')' expected but '}' found.
[error]         }
[error]         ^
```

The compilation fails only in 2.11.12 version and passes in the latter version
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This `mno = mno.convertTo[String],` has a trailing comma `,` before the closing parenthesis `)`.

Comment: So don't cut line numbers away from compiler output.

Answer (score 1):

Your case class

```
  case class XYZ(efg: String, mno: String)
```

then, define the protocol something like this.

```
  import spray.json._
  implicit object XYZFormat extends RootJsonFormat[XYZ] {
      // writer function
      def write(obj: XYZ): JsValue = JsObject(
        "efg" -> JsString(obj.efg),
        "mno" -> JsString(obj.mno)
      )

      // reader function
      def read(json: JsValue): XYZ =
        json.asJsObject.getFields("efg", "mno") match {
          case Seq(JsString(efg), JsString(mno)) => XYZ(efg, mno)
          case _ => throw DeserializationException("Not valid XYZ model")
        }
    }
```